# I can't use system.io.file.readalltext

Tags: vb.net

i'm programming a password manager and when you close the application, it saves the passwords in an encrypted file. when decrypting the file at the application opening, i get an error at this line of code.

```
Dim ciphertext As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\testing")
```

this is the error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path' C:\testing 'denied.'
```

Comment: You should not be writing files to the root of C:.  If you do, your application will require administrator permissions.  Look into writing to LocalAppData

Comment: That's what happens when c:\testing is a directory.  Try c:\testing\passwords, whatever you named the file when you saved the passwords.

Comment: i already gave my application administration permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must specify the exact text file name

   For Example:

   ```
   Dim ciphertext As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\testing\Txtfile.txt")
   ```
2. Try another drive for this work, you don't have access to this folder. You can change the access in file manager.